# Create patch file using msimsp.exe

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, patch, wix3.5

I have setups created by WIX.

I want to prepare patch installer to install/update the files that have been changed in the newer version.

I tried to create patch using WIX code, but was not successful. I also googled about msimsp.exe command but was not able to understand it properly.

Can someone post the example/source code on how can I achieve this?

Comment: What was not successful with torch/pyro approach? Can you post the error message(s)? I personally prefer this way of building patches - it is much clearer and doesn't require additional tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use my instruction: [WiX patching](http://alexyv.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wix-patching/).

I was able to create patch this way.
If you have more questions, I'll try to answer them.

Comment: Thanxs a lot for the link.
It worked fine. But 1 of my requirement was not met.
I have lots of .sql files. It compares them and list out the changed files. But I am not getting how can i command patch to execute this files from path.msp itself. Can you please guide me on this too.

Comment: @Sunil You should add executing these .sql files into your updated MSI. However, it might be not a good idea for a patch. Patch usually just updates the files. If you already have the CA that executes these .sql files, then you should update their conditions so that they're run when patching.